# CouchDB Replication / Timeout Error

Tags: android, couchdb, yocto, nosql

I'm running CouchDB with Yocto Dizzy on a LogicPD Torpedo with a 1GHz processor. I have multiple Android devices connected, making changes, and syncing with this database through some Java and Nodejs code. For the most part, it looks like the database is replicating properly across all devices.

However, I do have a frequent issue where a device will fall out of sync and the Android app on that device will have to be restarted. By "fall out of sync" I mean that changes are being made on one device, synced to the database, and not showing up on another device. I'm trying to troubleshoot this problem and I haven't been able to find any errors on the Android side. The errors I'm seeing in the CouchDB log are:

```
[Fri, 25 Sep 2015 14:47:59 GMT] [error] [<0.222.0>] ** Generic server <0.222.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.217.0>,killed}
** When Server state == {state,"http://X.XXX.X.X:XXXX/task/",20,[],
                           [<0.338.0>],
                           {[],[]}}
** Reason for termination == 
** killed

[Fri, 25 Sep 2015 14:47:59 GMT] [error] [<0.222.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                 {<0.222.0>,crash_report,
                  [[{initial_call,
                     {couch_replicator_httpc_pool,init,['Argument__1']}},
                    {pid,<0.222.0>},
                    {registered_name,[]},
                    {error_info,
                     {exit,killed,
                      [{gen_server,terminate,7,
                        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,804}]},
                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},
                    {ancestors,
                     [<0.217.0>,couch_replicator_job_sup,
                      couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                    {messages,[]},
                    {links,[<0.338.0>]},
                    {dictionary,[]},
                    {trap_exit,true},
                    {status,running},
                    {heap_size,610},
                    {stack_size,27},
                    {reductions,390}],
                   []]}}

[Fri, 25 Sep 2015 14:48:06 GMT] [error] [<0.130.0>] Error in replication `b16486bad369b219600dbd5bf0478e81+continuous+create_target` (triggered by document `9be140c9aa6334820aed80fa910275e4`): timeout
Restarting replication in 5 seconds.
[Fri, 25 Sep 2015 14:48:06 GMT] [error] [<0.88.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                   {<0.88.0>,supervisor_report,
                    [{supervisor,{local,couch_replicator_job_sup}},
                     {errorContext,shutdown_error},
                     {reason,killed},
                     {offender,
                         [{pid,<0.157.0>},
                          {name,
                              "98e4832e6f31a0962493d26092b5fe4e+continuous+create_target"},
                          {mfargs,{gen_server,start_link,undefined}},
                          {restart_type,temporary},
                          {shutdown,250},
                          {child_type,worker}]}]}}
```

When running the same programs and database on CentOS with an i7, it all works perfectly. I've tried mucking with tcp/ip kernel settings, as well as CouchDBs settings (local.ini, specifically os_process and timeout options).

Does anyone have any experience in this area? Any help would be greatly appreciated!